# Get a fileURL from MPMediaItem

Tags: ios, avasset, mpmediaitem

I am working on a wifi filesharing app. I have to send audio and video files as resources using Multi Peer Connectivity. The problem that i am facing right now is i can't get a fileURL which is required by MPC to send the resource. I need a way to get FileURL from MPMediaItem's AssetURL.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift version**

Drag and drop `TSLibraryImport` library to your project

```
let getimport = TSLibraryImport()
            let audioURL = generateMP3ExportUrl() //You can write your own output url
            getimport.importAsset(mpMediaItem.assetURL, to: audioURL) { (tslStatus) in
                if tslStatus?.status != nil{
                    if (tslStatus?.status)!.rawValue == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed.rawValue{
                        print("audio URL \(audioURL)")
                    }else{
                        print("error \(tslStatus?.error)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to mp3 requires two steps: exporting to mov and extracting audio data from mov file to mp3. This library does the export: https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport (I'm not an author, we are using it in our project. Peace :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But actually i am looking for a solution that doesn't involve third party libraries